# Argument type mismatch when attempting to invoke method

Tags: java, reflection, invoke

Say I have a `parameters` array:

```
Object[] parameters;
```

I also have a `types` list, that stores parameter types of a method.

```
List<Class<?>> types = Arrays.asList(Taxi.class, Bus.class);
```

Next instantiating the array:

```
parameters = new Object[types.size()];
```

Now, I fill the `parameters` array, with the given types in the `types` list:

```
int index = 0;
for (Class<?> type : types) {
    if (Taxi.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        parameters[index] = new Taxi();
    } else if (Bus.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        parameters[index] = new Bus();
    } 
    index ++;
}
```

Now I try to invoke the method that has the exactly same parameters as the `types` list:

```
someMethod.invoke(someObject, parameters);
```

The `someMethod` has the following signature:

```
public void someMethod(Taxi taxi, Bus bus);
```

And Java gives me an **IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch**. I understand why would this happen, as `parameters` is an Object array; are there any workarounds, though? Maybe like casting? But how?

Note that the 1) The objects in `types` list may NOT have a common superclass. 2) I know it's strange to not directly call the method but used the reflections to do so; this is because I am trying to implement an Event-like system, which requires "filling in" method parameters dynamically. 3) Parameter types (the `types` list) are already determined before the compilation.

The way of obtaining methods:

```
// Collect methods
Set<Method> methods;
Method[] publicMethods = someClass.getClass().getMethods();
methods = new HashSet<>(publicMethods.length, Float.MAX_VALUE);
Collections.addAll(methods, publicMethods);
Collections.addAll(methods, listener.getClass().getDeclaredMethods());
// Find annotated methods
for (final Method method : methods) {
    method.setAccessible(true);
    // Code from above
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do `Taxi` and `Bus` have a common parent class you could use for the `parameters`?

Comment: @Tichodroma Nope, they don't. I do this to try implementing an event system, everything compiles, and runtime error. :(

Comment: @TigerHix Please show 2 things: 1) declaration of method you are trying to invoke 2) code where you assign `parameters` variable to a new array

Comment: @VladimirS. I will update the post to show 1). May I know what's 2) about?

Comment: @TigerHix Under 2) I mean, where you create an array, something like this: `parameters = new Object[2]`

Comment: Please make sure that `someObject` is actually the instance of the same class which you get `someMethod` from.

Comment: Just checked, yes it is. The exception is about the mismatch in argument types, so I passed in the correct instance.

Comment: @TigerHix Taking into consideration your comments, the only reason I can imagine is some class-loading issue. Do you use any ClassLoaders explicitly in your code?

Comment: @VladimirS. Nope. Well I personally think the reason is, someMethod only accepts a Taxi and a Bus argument, but the parameters array is an object array. Java then thinks its incompatible. Though, the elements inside the parameters array are actually a Taxi and a Bus, therefore there should be a resolution to the case.

Comment: @TigerHix I don't think so, your code should work as is... Could you pls show how you obtain `someMethod` method reference?

Comment: Thread updated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TigerHix Ok, great, but could you show code where you assign value to `someMethod`?

Comment: There are many things in between the code of obtaining methods and invoking the method, but basically `someMethod` points to the same object as `method` in `for (final Method method : methods)`.

Comment: @TigerHix 1) I think you meant `someClass.getMethods();`, not `someClass.getClass().getMethods();`? Because in this case you get methods of class `java.lang.Class`, not `someClass`    2) Pls make sure that you choose correct `someMethod` among all `methods`, meaning that your class can have overloaded methods - with similar name but different parameters

Comment: @VladimirS. 1) Oops! The someClass here is actually an object, its a typo. 2) Will do tomorrow. I really appreciate your help throughout the hour!

Comment: @VladimirS. Thanks!! The problem was solved. I was actually having two arrays of parameters so I invoked the method like this: method.invoke(obj, params1, params2). Should've combined two arrays first..

Comment: @TigerHix ok, great :)

Answer (score 0):

Make an common super class like vehicle and derive bus and taxi from that class.

Then you just have to make `List<Vehicle> types = Arrays.asList(Taxi.class, Bus.class);`

Comment: The actual parameters do not inherit from a parent class; one can be int and the other can be String. Therefore I'm afraid this won't work.